# How to make material semi-transparent in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a simple shader with a water texure and I'd like to make it semi transparent.  Using Blender Internal engine, you can do this just by setting the alpha value on the shader.  Is there a way to do something similar in cycles?

Answer (score 2):

To make a semi transparent texture, place a diffuse and transparent shaders in the input of a mix node in the node editor.
[image]

To make water, use the glass shader and play around with the node values.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nodes used to make the material.  The latest “Principled” has a *transmission* slider that controls transparency.  In cycles that is all you need; with eeVee you also need to enable that feature.

[from the docs:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html?highlight=principled)

[image: node]